# ScreenShot solution takes a screentshot of my desktop

Tags: java, desktop, screenshot, fullscreen

I am currently making a fullscreen game and I want to be able to take some screenshots.
I have found this little code snippet:

```
BufferedImage image = 
new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(w.getX(), w.getY(),w.getWidth(),w.getHeight()));

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("C:\\Users\\Kaizer\\Desktop\\", "ScreenShot"             + counter + ".jpg"));
```

I know it doesnt look pretty, but it makes a screenshot, but from my desktop, and not my actual fullscreen game. The Windows screenshots does the same.

I know there is something I overlooked, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

By the way: this code is run when the player presses the F11 button. It is not its own method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrote your game with Swing or AWT, instead of using `Robot`, you can do the following:

```
private static void captureImage(Component c, String fileName)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    c.paint(img.getGraphics());

    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(fileName + ".jpg"));
}
```

Note: Depending on the `Component` you're using, it may or may not need to be visible. But seeing as you're taking a picture from a game, I'm pretty sure that won't matter.

Comment: I will try to play around with this. but what Component would be needed? the actual JFrame?

Comment: EDIT----------------------------
Tried this with the JFrame, but it just makes a white screen, thought it might be that i am using ignore repaint, and using double buffering and the update() and draw().
I tried turning ignore repaint off before saving the image and then turning it on again after the image was saved. but still only white screen.

Comment: AHA. I got it. I just had to change the method called from the c.paint to the draw method. Thanks a bunch. :)

Comment: It now also uses the current date to make the screenshot name, so they wont overwrite eachother as easily. adding the working code here in case someone didnt understand how i fixed it.

Comment: try
   {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    String currDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    JFrame Screenshot = s.getFrame();
    Screenshot.setIgnoreRepaint(false);
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(Screenshot.getWidth(), Screenshot.getHeight(),
      BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    draw(img.getGraphics());

    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("Screenshot" + currDate + "-"+ counter + ".jpg"));

    counter++;
    Screenshot.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
   }
   catch (IOException ex)
   {error handling here}

Comment: Using the `JFrame`'s `contentPane` ([`getContentPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane())) should work with the `paint` version.

Answer (score 0):

> from my desktop, and not my actual fullscreen game..

This is typical of the `Robot` (or standard OS screenshot software) when a game does active rendering.  AFAIU there is nothing that can be done about it (beyond - grab your screenshots with your phone camera).